# MVC: Convert route-parameter with dash to underscore to specify action name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a number of URLs that fit a {controller}/{action} pattern.

My problem is that I want to use multiple, dash-separated words for the second parameter (action). Since dashes are not allowed in action-method names, I cannot map this pattern with just one mapping, and I must resort to a new mapping for each new action, like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ContactUsForm", "forms/contact-us", new {
        action = "contact_us", 
        controller = "Forms"
    });
```

I have *many* forms that need this pattern, and their concerns are different enough that I cannot map them to the same action-method.

**QUESTION**
Is there a simple way around this, say some way to map {controller}/{some-string} to the action "some_string", and route all of my form URLs in one go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify action name in the attribute and use it without any changes in routes:

```
[ActionName("some-string")]
public ActionResult MyActionHere(string id) 
{

}
```